# Reputation bug or a Reputation display bug

Tags: support, status-bydesign

I can't understand my reputation chart for today, is it due to rep-cap or something else?

[image]

Only for the highlighted part, I mean blank rep for upvote and 8 rep for an upvote, sounds weird. It even started before i completed 200 rep bar.

Comment: Isn't this question suited for a more general StackExchange site rather than Hinduism meta?

Comment: @PratikBhat In general, users are welcome to ask support questions on their local meta (i.e. this one) or on "big" meta (i.e. [meta.se]). This question is fine where it is.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That is not a bug, it is correct, I checked your reputation tab, you have

4 answers which are accepted, sums up to 60 + 200 Reputation from edits + upvotes

Why you got **+8**?

You have scored all the reputation points in the multiples of 10s, BUT you have **+4** for *Suggested Edits* and a **-2** for an answer, so that creates a **+2** offset

So if your total is 192, and you get an upvote, system will serve you 8 points, i.e 200 - 192 (Accepted answers reputation won't count here)

And the blank ones denotes that other users upvoted you on those answers but because of reputation cap, you didn't got any reputation out of it.

Comment: Ahhhh....so much loss of reputation/